# Type inference with union types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typing, inference

I have a type C which is the union of A and B types. I have a variable of type C and after assigning a B type it seems that the type infer is not working when B and C have one property with the same name.

```
class A {
    prop1: string;
}

class B {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
}

type C = A | B;

class test {
    thisIsC: C;

    constructor() {
        this.thisIsC = this.getTypeB(); //This doesn't make thisIsC inferred to B
        const b = this.getTypeB(); //This works fine
        const a = this.thisIsC;
    }

    getTypeB(): B {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

If the properties don't collide, the problem doesn't appear and the type infer is done properly (for example):

```
class A {
    prop1: string;
}

class B {
    prop2: string;
    prop3: string;
}

type C = A | B;

class test {
    thisIsC: C;

    constructor() {
        this.thisIsC = this.getTypeB(); //This makes thisIsC be inferred to B type
        const a = this.thisIsC;
    }

    getTypeB(): B {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

My question is if I can do something to improve this type inference (with colliding parameters) just to tell typescript that the variable "thisIsC" is of type B after the getTypeB() call. Apparently "If we have a value that has a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union." which makes sense to me, but in my code, "getTypeB()" returns explicitly a type B. I just can solve the problem creating an aux variable or doing a manual type assertion with a type guard but I want to know if I can do anything to modify how this internally works.

Playground with the error:
https://t.ly/iFZ0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update this sandbox to show the error : https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa1gHsB2EAuATgK7B6YEAUAlIquungBYCWEAdAA4GYcCM0AXmgByAB7CA3HWgBfaei49eALmj4CzbAHMpKOSlShIMAEK009LLkIkylGsgsMW7RX0Ejxu+tCatO3BwATB7CAJ6S0vo+bipqhJo68tBuQarqibr6qHhhHACm0ADCHvAAPtAmuobgUL75+OY+fhAAkhBFqkXVThg46rbk1E0+9C1sLe0lQuNa+XgAKnn5JtQS0AD0Gwsu0AAmmA3YwnjQALZgANaFkx3QmgBm+QT5e76Ylck+Vo0ARh6zeZLAqrKjrLY7VjQADu5EuMAemnyX0s-VOYABLgmLim3no2V6c0Wy1BqjMjlG9BeeCIBGw0Gw+WhlTWyX0BKMdTwDTwIQpYxxHS6PW+aOIpCGDhRzn8t2mvixROBKzWm22uwu1xgcugv0Kj2er3elV8y2lfWs0AxMyxcrx6AJPiVJOoZJGlOptPpjOZoPtslQMiAA

Comment: @TusharShahi done, thanks https://t.ly/iFZ0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know if I can do anything to modify how this internally works.

I would recommend [tagging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) your `A` and `B` types.

```js
class A {
    prop1: string;
    tag: "A";

    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = "helloworld";
        this.tag = "A"
    }
}

class B {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    tag: "B";

    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = "helloworld";
        this.prop2 = "prop2";
        this.tag = "B";
    }
}

type C = A | B;

class test {
    thisIsC: C;

    constructor() {
        this.thisIsC = this.getTypeB();
        const b = this.thisIsC;

        b.prop2;
    }

    getTypeB(): B {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

After tagging them typescript is able to properly infer the types.

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oAcBOB7TAjAFzQQAu2AlgHYDmA3KhtGWLSQESweMpMbBc1ctgCuwMrmwAKAJSJ+zdGQAWlCADoc+AtAC80DioCmIELgDuUkABMeipavUbWtfYe4OAvqh98UoJAwAEIKaBjahCQiNAwOkQBM0RSxvMyunMH2-syCwhTikjLyyOFKLGqakboGRqbmVti22eXKlVp4mAnuHIktrU6arj1ZaRh+fqhkAJ6YxtAAwu7wAD7QwbyogVAsxuRh6ZUAkhALJAubZdB5IoVScgcD7YMnSwaDGrTGZAAqs8bBORjco3MjQABG7g+L1Ol1aEI6+ASwOgkyuX1+-0BshIoVK8Ow31E2Go0Goxgs6yB3l8QA)