# TypeScript: Inference Issue with Mapped Types and Discriminated Unions

Tags: typescript, typing, discriminated-union, mapped-types

I know that much has already been said about typing discriminated unions, but I could not find a solution for my particular case yet. Say I have the following code:

```
type A = {label: 'a', options: {x: number}; text: string}; // label is intended to act as tag
type B = {label: 'b', options: {y: string}; text: string};
type C = A | B;
type D<T extends C> = {
  label: T['label'];
  displayOptions: T['options'];
  complexValue: T extends B ? T['options']['y'] : never;
};
function f<U extends D<C>>(u: U) {
  if (u.label === 'a') {
    u.displayOptions // is inferred as {x: number} | {y: string} instead of just {x: number}
  }
}
```

At the commented place, I would expect the type of `u.displayOptions` to be inferred as `{x: number}` because `label` should act as a "tag" as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578971/type-inference-with-union-types-in-typescript) for a similar problem. But this doesn't work; the type is still `{x: number} | {y: string}`.

I suspect that is because in the definition of `D`, I only indirectly use `T['label']` and `T['options']`, since it does work if I would use a property `type: T` in `D` instead, and then `if (t.type.label === 'a')`.
However, it seems I cannot do that for the following reasons:

1. I do not want to use all properties of `T` (or `C`) in `D` (such as `text`).
2. Such properties that I do want to use may be renamed (like `displayOptions` instead of `options`).
3. I want to use additional properties that depend on `T`, like `complexValue`.

Is there any (preferrably simple) solution that can achieve all of this?

Comment: The type narrowing won't work as you expect with generics. Actually, you don't need generics at all. Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGBEXm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it works! The key idea seems to be `T extends T`, didn't think of that. Would be very thankful for an explanation, also why it does not work as expected with generics.

Comment: sure, will in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generics, there is no safe way for the compiler to narrow the type, which is described in [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) since we don't know the passed type exactly. Example:

```
function f<T extends 'a' | 'b'>(x: T) {
  if (x === 'a') {
    x; //  T extends "a" | "b"
  }
}
```

In reality, generics are not what you need in your use case. What you actually need are [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). *Unions* are distributed when they are checked against some condition (`extends something`) and to make sure that every member of the union passes the check we need to find some condition that will be always true. For instance `T extends any` or even `T extends T`. By *distributing*, we will re-create the union again with modified/added fields. To remove the unnecessary fields we will use the built-in [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) utility type. Since we are adjusting the members of the union separately, we will also adjust  the way an extra field is added:

```
type D<T extends C = C> = T extends T
  ? Omit<T, 'options' | 'text'> & {
      displayOptions: T['options'];
    } & (T extends B ? { complexValue: T['options']['y'] } : {})
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
// (Omit<A, "options" | "text"> & {
//   displayOptions: {
//       x: number;
//   };
// }) | (Omit<B, "options" | "text"> & {
//   displayOptions: {
//       y: string;
//   };
// } & {
//   complexValue: string;
// })
type Result = D;
```

Even though the type looks correct it is really hard to read. To fix it we can use [Prettify](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/prettify.d.ts?plain=1#L15) utility type defined in the [type-samurai](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai) package:

```
type Prettify<T> = T extends infer R
  ? {
      [K in keyof R]: R[K];
    }
  : never;
```

Basically, it creates a copy of the passed type and by using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) remaps it, which forces the compiler to remove the unwanted intersection and aliases:

```
// {
//   label: 'a';
//   displayOptions: {
//     x: number;
//   };
// }
// | {
//   label: 'b';
//   displayOptions: {
//     y: string;
//   };
//   complexValue: string;
// };
type Result = Prettify<D>;
```

Now, you can accept a parameter of type `Result` and everything should work as expected. Final testing:

```
function f(u: Result) {
  if (u.label === 'a') {
    u.displayOptions; // {x: number}
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-kRJKyWPxtKrCAMDioKyIUrlKq1S4Nc6OSocOiWYJQSq0jibfOF4Cy1GDagrFsAOk9qAQ8EQeq7YbRgw4-cxAZNIYYShUSGtnB4PRdaK3AiAA)